# Trying to pass an array of data to a Spring MVC Controller using Ajax

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

I writing code to send data from javascript to a Spring MVC Controller using Ajax.

It appears that my Ajax code is working fine as my "success" message is printed in the client console, so I am assuming the POST was executed. However, my Controller doesn't seem to be getting called as its message is never printed to the server console.

My Ajax code:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#submit-btn-2").on("click", function () {
                    var idList = [];
                    $(".vm-row").has(":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
                        idList.push($(this).attr('id'));
                    });
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 'submitVendors',
                        data: {idList:idList},
                        success: function(id) {
                            console.log("SUCCESS: ", idList);                           
                        },
                        error : function(e) {
                            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
                        },
                        done : function(e) {
                            console.log("DONE")
                        }
                    })
                });
            });
</script>
```

Clicking the associated button causes this message to be printed to the client console:

```
SUCCESS:  Array(3)
```

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/submitVendors", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody 
    String submitVendors(@RequestParam("idList[]") String[] idList, HttpServletRequest request) {

        String vid = request.getSession().getAttribute("vid").toString();
        System.out.println("Inside submitVendors service.");

        for (String id : idList)
        {
            System.out.println("It actually worked: " + id);
        }

        return "vendormanagement";
    }
```

No error of any sort is printed to the server console and neither are messages.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

`data: JSON.stringify(idList),`
and 
`(@RequestBody String[] idList)`

OR this :

`data: {"idList":idList.toString()},`
and 
`(@RequestParam(value = "idList") List<String> idList)`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not fix my issue. I think I know what the problem is, I just don't know how to resolve. The ajax is being called in vm.jsp. It then sends the post to appname/vm/submitVendors. But I don't think that is where the Controller is supposed to be called at. It is very confusing.

Comment: check whether you are giving correct url path: $.ajax({         type: "POST",
                        url: '/appname/controllerPath/submitVendors',

Answer (score 0):

pass the RequestParam name mached with variable name return by ajax,

```
@RequestParam(value="idList") ArrayList<String> idList)
```

add/ change the following properties into/ in ajax function

```
dataType: 'json',
data:{idList : idList.toString()}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the RequestParam name did not fix my problem. My System.out.println messages are still not being printed in server console. I need the HttpServletRequest request as it is being used to pass a variable to this Controller from a different Controller. It is not being used by my Ajax.

Comment: @RyanSwanson please share the vm.jsp file